# ExtJS MVC: should controllers be specified within requires for application?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4.1, extjs-mvc

If an Ext.application has the following controllers:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});

Ext.application({        
    name: 'MyApp',
    appFolder: 'app',

    controllers: [
        'Ctrl1',
        'Ctrl2'
    ],

    launch: function() { ... }
});
```

should it also include the controllers in `controllers` in the `requires` section, i.e. add

```
requires: [
    'MyApp.controller.Ctrl1',
    'MyApp.controller.Ctrl2'
],
```

within the above class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The short answer is NO.

The long answer is that the `controllers`, `models`, `views` and `stores` configs all translate to `requires`. The bit that does the magic is in the [Ext.app.Controller](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.app.Controller-cfg-models) class:

```
onClassExtended: function(cls, data, hooks) {
    var Controller = Ext.app.Controller,
        className, namespace, onBeforeClassCreated, requires, proto, match;

    className  = Ext.getClassName(cls);
    namespace  = Ext.Loader.getPrefix(className) ||
                 ((match = className.match(/^(.*)\.controller\./)) && match[1]);

    if (namespace && namespace !== className) {
        onBeforeClassCreated = hooks.onBeforeCreated;
        requires = [];

        hooks.onBeforeCreated = function(cls, data) {
            proto = cls.prototype;

            Controller.processDependencies(proto, requires, namespace, 'model', data.models);
            Controller.processDependencies(proto, requires, namespace, 'view', data.views);
            Controller.processDependencies(proto, requires, namespace, 'store', data.stores);
            Controller.processDependencies(proto, requires, namespace, 'controller', data.controllers);

            // this is the line to look at!!!
            Ext.require(requires, Ext.Function.pass(onBeforeClassCreated, arguments, this));
        };
    }
},
```

Your application is just an `Ext.app.Application` class that inherits from `Ext.app.Controller`; thus the `controllers` config also translates to `requires`.

Answer (score 2):

No, that is not necessary. Here is an example of working `app.js` I am using right now:

```
Ext.Loader.setConfig({enabled:true});
Ext.Loader.setPath('Ext.ux', '../extjs/examples/ux');

Ext.application({
    name: 'FPPP',

    autoCreateViewport: true,

    controllers: [
        'Main',
        'List',
        'Report'
    ]

});
```

There's also the [Sencha MVC guide](http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/guide/application_architecture)

Comment: Is the `Ext.Loader.setPath` statement also necessary for your `FFFP` location, for instance, usually located within relative directory `app`?

Comment: @JosvicZammit I had one extjs framework library used by multiple apps so I needed to give my app a relative path to the framework to get all the ux classes. As long as you match the namespace with the directory structure you wouldn't need to do that.